# AngualrJs ionic : Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TeamDetailCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller

I have this Controller :

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('eliteApp').controller('TeamDetailCtrl',['$stateParams',$ionicPopup,'eliteApi',TeamDetailCtrl]);
  function TeamDetailCtrl($stateParams ,$ionicPopup , eliteApi){
    var vm = this;
    //console.log('$stateParams',$stateParams);
    //$stateParams are using to access to parameters in the link
    vm.teamId = Number($stateParams.id);

    eliteApi.getLeagueData().then(function(data){
      var team = _.chain(data.teams)
        .flatten("divisionTeams")
        .find({"id":vm.teamId})
        .value();

      vm.teamName = team.name;

      vm.games = _.chain(data.games)
        .filter(isTeamInGame)
        .map(function(item){
          var isTeam1 = (item.team1Id === vm.teamId ? true : false);
          var opponentName = isTeam1 ? item.team2 : item.team1;
          var scoreDisplay = getScoreDisplay(isTeam1 , item.team1ScoreDisplay,item2.team2ScoreDisplay);
          return{
            gamed : item.id,
            opponent: opponentName,
            time: item.time,
            location: item.location,
            locationUrl: item.location.locationUrl,
            scoreDisplay: item.scoreDisplay,
            homeAway: (isTeam1 ? "vs." : "at")
          };
        })
        .value();

      vm.teamStanding = _.chain(data.standings)
        .flatted("divisionStandings")
        .find({"teamId" : vm.teamId})
        .value();
    })



    vm.following = false;

    vm.toggleFollow = function(){
      if(vm.following){
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'Unfollow?',
          template: 'Are you sure you want to unfollow?'
        });
        confirmPopup.then(function(res){
          if(res){
            vm.following = !vm.following;
          }
        })
      }
        else{
          vm.following = !vm.following;
        }

    };

    function isTeamInGame(item){
      return item.item1Id === vm.teamId || item.team2Id === vm.teamId;
    }
    function getScoreDisplay (isTeam1 , team1Score , team2Score) {
      if (team1Score && team2Score) {
        var teamScore = (isTeam1 ? team1Score : team2Score);
        var opponentScore = (isTeam1 ? team2Score : team1Score);
        var winIndicator = teamScore > opponentScore ? "W: " : "L:";
        return winIndicator + teamScore + "-" + opponentScore;
      }
      else
      {
        return"";
      }
    }
  };
})
```

And team-detail.html file :

```html
<ion-view ng-controller="TeamDetailCtrl as vm" title="{{vm.teamName}}">
  <ion-content class="has-header">

    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-button-right">
        <h2>Record: {{vm.teamStanding.wins}}--{{vm.teamStanding.losses}}</h2>
        <button class="button button-positive icon-left"
                ng-class="{'icon-checkmark-round': vm.following,'ion-plus-round button-outline':!vm.following}" ng-click="vm.toggleFollow()">
          {{vm.following ? "Following" : "Not Following"}}
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="game in vm.games" ui-sref=
        "app.game({id: game.gameId})">
        {{game.opponent}} {{game.scoreDisplay}}

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-20 col-center">
            <p>{{game.time | date:'m/d/yy'}}</p>
            <p>{{game.time | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h3>{{game.homeAway}} {{game.opponent}}</h3>
            <p>{{game.location}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-20 col-center">
            <h4 class="positive">{{game.scoreDisplay}}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In this HTML Page when i click on any link it will redirect me to team-detail.html page with the proper id :

```html
<ion-view title="teams" ng-controller="TeamsCtrl as vm">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list">
      <div ng-repeat="division in vm.teams">
        <div class="item item-divider item-energized">{{division.divisionName}}</div>
        <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="team in division.divisionTeams"
           href="#/app/teams/{{team.id}}">{{team.name}}
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I searched a lot but with no solution .
I did not forget to add the link to index.html page .

Routing file app.js :

```js
angular.module("eliteApp" , ["ionic","angular-cache"])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform, CacheFactory) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }

      CacheFactory("leagueDataCache",{storageMode:"localStorage", maxAge:50000 , deleteOnExpire:"aggressive"});
      CacheFactory("leaguesCache",{storageMode:"localStorage", maxAge:50000 , deleteOnExpire:"aggressive"});
      CacheFactory("myTeamsCache",{storageMode:"localStorage"});
      CacheFactory("staticCache",{storageMode:"localStorage"});

    });
  })

.config(function($stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('home' ,{
        abstract: true,
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl:"app/home/home.html"
      })
      .state('home.leagues',{
        url: "/leagues",
        views:{
          "tab-leagues":{
            templateUrl: "app/home/leagues.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('home.myteams',{
        url: "/myteams",
        views:{
          "tab-myteams":{
            templateUrl: "app/home/myteams.html"
          }
        }
      })
      
    .state('app', {
        abstract:true,
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl:"app/layout/menu-layout.html"
      })

      .state('app.teams',{
        url: "/teams",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/team/teams.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.teams-details',{
        url: "/teams/:id",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/team/team-detail.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.game',{
        url: "/game/:id",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/game/game.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.standings',{
        url: "/standings",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/standings/standings.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.locations',{
        url: "/locations",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/locations/locations.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.rules',{
        url: "/rules",
        views:{
          "mainContent":{
            templateUrl: "app/rules/rules.html"
          }
        }
      })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/teams');
  });
```

Comment: Have you defined the `TeamDetailCtrl` controller ?

Comment: post edited !! you can see it .

Comment: Show us routing in app.js

Comment: I appended it to the question .